# Browser not showing added content via CSS using ::after

Tags: html, css

I am testing some css and have found that the browsers (Chrome, firefox) will not show the ::after content I am specifying.  Fiddler show is correctly, but the browser will not.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testdiv">
            <main>
                <section>
                    <p>
                        I want to put number '123' here: 
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        And I want it here too: 
                    </p>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#testdiv main p { margin: 0; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 700;}
#testdiv main p + p { font-size: 1.0em; font-weight: 300;} 
#testdiv main p::after { content:'123'; }
```

Fiddle: (shows correct)
https://jsfiddle.net/bg1tg8nc/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain *"Fiddler show is correctly, but the browser will not."* ? What are the Firefox and Chrome versions?

Comment: does it even happen when you set the position of the pseudo elements to `absolute`?

Comment: It's working fine in Firefox 43.0.4. What browser versions are you using?

Comment: I tested your code in several browsers and it is working correctly for me.

Comment: Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m shows it OK

Comment: I am using:
Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit), Safari Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9), and FireFox 42.0 (and upgraded to 43.0.4)

None of these browsers will show "123" after the colon, as expected from the ::after(content: '123').

If you view the same code in the fiddle link, you will see the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HA I figured out how to fix the issue!

If you take the above CSS code and reorder it like this:

```
#testdiv main p::after { content:'123'; }
#testdiv main p { margin: 0; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: 700;}
#testdiv main p + p { font-size: 1.0em; font-weight: 300;}
```

it works fine.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I am marking this as the answer.  I know it has worked for several people in several browsers.  I don't know how else to close out the issue.